# assigning var to var -- will it work?

Tags: c, string, wrapper

I am trying to do something useful for a wrapper I am working out.  I am writing a wrapper for the standard string library for C because I don't like it.

I don't want to introduce C strings to my wrapper right now.  Ihave a struct called `str which contains the string's length and the buffer:

```
struct str
{
    char *buf;
    size_t len;
};
```

In my header file I have this:

```
typedef struct str str;
```

Now I have implemented encapsulation (I think).

So I declare strings like this:

```
str *a_string = NULL;
```

I have already done everything that I want to do with this, but I have one problem.   What I would like to add something like this for one function:

str.h:

```
extern str *str_str(str *, char *);
```

and str.c

```
str *str_str(str *buf, char *ns)
{
    buf->len = strlen(ns);
    buf->buf = (char *) malloc(buf->len + 1);
    strncpy(buf->buf, ns, buf->len);
    return buf;
}
```

and testing this works well:

```
str *s = str_new();
printf("%s\n", str_cstr(str_str(s, "hello")));

output: hello
```

but will this work?

```
str_assign(s, str_str(s, "ok"));
```

That's essentially assigning `s` to `s`, I think.  When I print, it prints nothing!

I don't get any errors!
All help is greatly appreciated.  I am fairly new with the C language.

Source of `str_assign()`:

```
void str_assign(str *s1, str *s2)
{
    s1->len = s2->len;
    s1->buf = (char *) malloc(s2->len + 1);
    strncpy(s1->buf, s2->buf, s2->len);
}
```

Comment: Why are you typing code instead of copy and pasting it?  That's dumb.  Select the code, press Ctrl+C, then go into your browser and press Ctrl+V.  In the body of str_str, I think you meant to write `strlen(ns)` instead of `strlen(s)`.

Comment: You forgot to put a `return` statement in `str_str` so it will not compile, or if it does it will do something bad.

Comment: i did mean ns, sorry.  is this not enough information?  i just posted the problem.  the two functions are identical as written in the .c file.  i do return s in str_str in my source, i must have forgot to add the return statement in my document.

Comment: I think there is a bug in your `str_assign` function that makes it not work when the two arguments are the same string.  Post the source code of that, and use copying and pasting this time.

Comment: Post the code for `str_assign`. Does it `free()` the current `str.buf` before assigning the new value? Do you test for self-assignment?

Comment: i posted it please refresh the page

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I basically don't understand , what is this str_new() is doing , why it cannot be done like this.  `struct str s; function(&s);`

Comment: It isn't clear what the `str_new()` is doing, but presumably it is equivalent to: `str *str_new(void) { str *res = malloc(sizeof(str)); res->len = 0; res->buf = malloc(1); res->buf[0] = '\0'; return res; }` as this is about the only formulation that maintains the required constraints for the type.  I'm also not particularly sure, @dicaprio, why you're asking me rather than john who asked the question.  Your design is a valid alternative, though it is nice to be able to initialize on the declaration line, so I tend to prefer the `str_new()` notation.

Comment: @dicaprio: the other reason it can't be done as `struct str s;` is that the `str` type is opaque; you can only allocate pointers to the type outside the library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm just seeking experts advice on my opinion and hence I put question to you. My emphasis is more on using the better alternative and thanks you answered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is C, but it is useful to compare this with C++.  When you write an assignment operator in C++, you always have to consider the case of self-assignment. The same applies when you do the equivalent job in C.

Therefore, I think you need:

```
void str_assign(str *s1, const str *s2)
{
    if (s1 != s2)
    {
        free(s1->buf);  // Added!
        s1->len = s2->len;
        if ((s1->buf = (char *) malloc(s2->len + 1)) != 0)
            memcpy(s1->buf, s2->buf, s2->len + 1);
        else
            s1->len = 0;  // Is this sufficiently safe with a null buf?
    }
}
```

You can use `memcpy()` because (a) the strings are guaranteed to be disjoint, and (b) you know how long the string is, so you don't need to check for the end of string at each step of the way as you would with `strncpy()` or `strcpy()`.

Actually, there's a case for saying you should never need to use `strcpy()` or `strncpy()` or `strcat()` or `strncat()`; you should always know how long the source and destination strings are (otherwise you can't be sure that there won't be a buffer overflow), so you can always use `memmove()` or `memcpy()` instead.

---

I also note that you're going to have to worry about memory leaks at some point.  I just amended the assignment above to release the old string before overwriting it with the new.

You could also optimize operations by only allocating new space when the new string is longer than the old.  You could consider using `realloc()` instead of `malloc()`, too.  However, you must be careful of the memory leak trap.  This is the wrong way to use `realloc()`:

```
s1->buf = realloc(s1->buf, s1->len + 1);
```

If `realloc()` fails, you've just overwritten your point with a null - losing the only reference you had to the old space.  You should always store the result of `realloc()` in a different variable from the first argument:

```
char *new_buf = realloc(s1->buf, s1->len + 1);
if (new_buf == 0)
    ...handle out of memory condition...
```

You might eventually decide to keep two lengths in your structure - the space allocated and the space used.  Then you can reuse space more efficiently, only allocating more space when the new string is longer than the previously allocated space, but still allowing you to shorten a string at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a return statement in your `str_str` function, so add `return buf;`.

If you think about it a little bit you will see there is a bug in your `str_assign` function because after you change the `s1->buf` pointer you are actually changing `s2->buf` also because they point to the same struct.  Here is an implementation that should work better for you:

```
str * str_assign(str * dest, const str * src)
{
    char * old_buffer = dest->buf;
    if (src->buf)
    {
       char * buf = malloc(src->len+1);
       strncpy(buf, src->buf, src->len);
       dest->buf = buf;
       dest->len = src->len;
    }
    else
    {
       dest->buf = 0;
    }

    if (old_buffer)
    {
      free(old_buffer);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Cool!  I edited my answer several times so make sure you refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I see a `memory leak` in the following code!

```
void str_assign(str *s1, str *s2)
{
    s1->len = s2->len;
    s1->buf = (char *) malloc(s2->len + 1);
    strncpy(s1->buf, s2->buf, s2->len);
}
```

if `s1` and `s2` point to the same memory location, then you're allocating new memory using `malloc` and assigning it to the pointer which is already pointing to a valid memory location and containing a valid `struct str` data! .. this can be avoided by putting a simple check by doing the following

```
void str_assign(str *s1, str *s2)
{
    if (s1 == s2)
        return;

    /* 
    if s1 is pointing to any valid memory 
    then free it before making it point to 
    the memory that was allocated by malloc.
    */
    if (s1 != NULL)
        free(s1);

    if ((s1->buf = (char *) malloc(s2->len + 1)) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory\n");
        return;
    }

    s1->len = s2->len;
    strncpy(s1->buf, s2->buf, s2->len);
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what did I miss? hints please.

Comment: `s1->buf` contains allocated memory - before you overwrite it with the newly allocated memory.  That's a leak!  (I missed it at first, too!)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for pointing it out! Its a good point. I've corrected the code. Let me know if something is missing! :)

Comment: Since you want an assignment to overwrite the previous value, you should probably use either `free()` to release the previously allocated memory or `realloc()` to resize it to the correct size for the new string.  You probably should not decline to overwrite the string; we aren't trying to make a functional language with immutable variables.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What if the function is passed a pointer that is valid and we realloc it? Wouldn't it be good to just reject the request unless they give us genuine (problem-less) pointer variables to work with?!

Comment: This is an assignment operation.  It seems reasonable to me to want to do: `str *s1 = str_new(); str_assign(s1, somestr); printf("%s\n", str_cstr(s1)); str_assign(s1, anotherstr); printf("%s\n", str_cstr(s1));` - that is, to assign different values to the same string at different times, and to use those values.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Point noted. Its makes a lot of sense to `free()` the old memory and `malloc()` new memory (or) `realloc()` and `memset()`. I've updated the code to capture this scenario. Thanks for all your clarification!